# How to pre-set the colours of each bar in my iOS Charts bar chart?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

As you can see from the image below won = red, lost = green.
I believe this is random when the chart is created.

[image]

I want to set the won: green, drawn: yellow, lost: red.

This is my chart code:

```
 func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]){

    let formato:BarChartFormatter = BarChartFormatter()
    formato.setValues(values: dataPoints)
    let xaxis:XAxis = XAxis()

    let xAxis : XAxis = self.barChartView.xAxis;
    barChartView.noDataText = "you need to provide some data for the chart."

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = Array()

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count
    {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    xaxis.valueFormatter = formato
    barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xaxis.valueFormatter
     let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Games Played")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet])
    chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()

    barChartView.data = chartData

    chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
    barChartView.data = chartData

}
```

and this is the code for my `BarChartFormatter`

```
public class BarChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter
{
var matches: [String]! = ["Lost", "Drawn", "Won"]

public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String{

    return matches[Int(value)]

}

public func setValues(values: [String])
{
    self.matches = values
}


}
```

Comment: You're setting the colors yourself when you do `chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()`.  Set it to an array of whatever colors you want the bars to be.

Comment: Cheers Dan, would you mind telling me how i do that?

Comment: Which part do you now know how to do?  Do `chartDataSet.colors = [.green, .yellow, .red]` or whatever colors you want the bars to be.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Dan that's worked!